# Full screen background image not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add full screen background image on a page. The code i have written shows full image on chrome but it shows only half a screen on Firefox. I used vw and vh. but it doesn't fit the screen. It shows scrollbar. I tried some code which is from stack overflow. But none of them work here. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.welcome-wrap {
  background: url('https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/paper.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

.welcome-wrap-bg {
  background: rgba(12, 42, 59, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.welcome-img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.welcome-greet1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffcc29;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.welcome-greet2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.smile {
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class="welcome-wrap">
  <div class="welcome-wrap-bg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <img class="welcome-img" alt="success" src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/congrates1.svg">
          <h2 class="welcome-greet1">CONGRATULATIONS!!</h2>
          <h1 class="welcome-greet2">[Site Name] Welcomes You <img class="smile" alt="Smile" src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/smile.svg"></h1>
          <div class="text-center mrgn-top-50">
            <a href="/dashboard/buying/submit-RFQ.html" class="btn btn-pi radius-2 btn-md" data-original-title="" title="">Create Your Company Profile&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make your background-size cross-browser, it means add the following code to you css selector:

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```

so your final code should be like that:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.welcome-wrap {
  background: url('https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/paper.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

.welcome-wrap-bg {
  background: rgba(12, 42, 59, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.welcome-img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.welcome-greet1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffcc29;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.welcome-greet2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.smile {
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class="welcome-wrap">
  <div class="welcome-wrap-bg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <img class="welcome-img" alt="success" src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/congrates1.svg">
          <h2 class="welcome-greet1">CONGRATULATIONS!!</h2>
          <h1 class="welcome-greet2">[Site Name] Welcomes You <img class="smile" alt="Smile" src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/piimages-new/welcome/smile.svg"></h1>
          <div class="text-center mrgn-top-50">
            <a href="/dashboard/buying/submit-RFQ.html" class="btn btn-pi radius-2 btn-md" data-original-title="" title="">Create Your Company Profile&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

if it doesn't work, make sure that firefox is up to date, if so, delete cookies from firefox and refresh your page, good luck

Comment: Its not working. I cleared the cache and Firefox is on up to date.

Comment: I tried as you said but its not working. https://html.paperindex.com/welcome-to-pi.html

Comment: i can see your problem now, the solution that i found is giving to your welcome-wrap class a height of 100vh, and add overflow:hidden to your body,this will solve your problem, i will update the solution so you can see it better